# symfony form with new files via Vich Uploader

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, vichuploaderbundle

Iam trying to build a smarter upload structure for my app. until now I had the code for uploading files in the controller and everything was more manual. Now I want to use the VichUploader in Symfony, but I have problems to implement it with multiple files.

First, I dont have an Entity with a file but an Entity that holds multiple File Entities. To be more clearly: The Entity `Document` has a `oneToMany` relation to `File`. So I build a form with a CollectionType:

```
$builder->add('files', Type\CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => Type\FileType::class
])
```

But because there is not file yet when I add a new Document, no upload field is shown. And even when there are already files (on edit form), there shouldn't be upload fields shown but text fields with file names.

How can I achieve that? Do i still need to add an umapped field files_new() with a multiple FileType? Then the VichUploader automatic stuff would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass an empty file object you should have your html fil input as it is a collection

In your controller (I don't have your code)

```
$entity = new Entity()
$entity->addFile(new FileEntity())//Add an empty file object


$form = $this->createForm(YourType::class, $entity);
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Comment: ok that works, but I still have the main problem with the multiple File Upload. But because it was not really pointed out in my question, I will start a new one and accept your answer